# How to avoid null exception when using equals() method in Java

Tags: java, equals

I was trying to compare the name of two different Objects, but I kept getting exceptions when using the `equals()` method to compare an item to null. I've tried so many ways, including other.equals(haha), haha.equals(other), etc, but all failed.

```java
public final class ItemImpl implements Item {
  private final String name;

  public ItemImpl(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("name cannot be null!");
    }
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    Object haha = name;

    return other.toString().equals(haha.toString());
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) for tolerance of nulls.

`Objects.equals(a,b);` 
does the job for you, in your case you have also to look that the toString method which you call is not on a null reference.
So use: 
`return other != null && Objects.equals(toString(), other.toString());`